# Equalization algorithm only on non-null pixels?

Tags: matlab

Is there a way that algorithm like histogram equalizaton and Contrast Limited Adaptive Histogram Equalization be made to work only on non-null pixel values of Image matrix?

```
 I=imread('someImage');
 J=histeq(I);    %I want this step to be performed on non-null pixels only
```

I mean that the the range of the values be stretched(since that what equalization does?) only on the pixels that have non zero count.For example in following figure histogram equalization stretched image to the null pixels at both end.But my requirement is to apply it only at the region where there are bars on the graph.

[image]

Comment: Isn't the point with [histogram equalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_equalization) to stretch any, say, integer (as in your example above) range image, to the full [0, 255] span? (In so enhancing the contrast).

Comment: you are absolutely right but I have specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward method since `histeq` transforms NaN into zeros. You can map the zeros, remove them, perform the `histeq` and add the zeros back.

```
% data
A = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(A);

% zero map
I_zero_map = (I == 0); % store the location of the zero
shape_I = size(I); % store the original shape of your matrix

% build hist without the zeros
I_temp = I(:); % copy I with a vector shape
I_temp(I_temp == 0) = []; % remove the zeros from the vector
I_temp = histeq(I_temp); % perform histogram equalisation

% reshape the matrice by adding the zeros
for ii = find(I_zero_map(:))'
    I_temp = [I_temp(1:ii-1); 0; I_temp(ii: end)]; % add the original zeros
end
I = reshape(I_temp, shape_I) % reshape to the original size
```

Comment: @Khan, I changed the example to work with actual images loaded from `imread`. Your error is from the fact that you don't add all the zeros properly in the for loop. Can you share your data?